# iOS Appstore App Update - Code Signing

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have a doubt on Code Signing during Appstore submission. I already submitted an app to appstore with the profiles and certs created and its currrently in appstore. Unfortunately, i lost my machine where i had backup of those profiles and certs. I know that Prov Profile can be downloaded from my developer account.

My Doubt here is, 1) As i dont have backup of .p12, should i need to raise a request for new certificate from my keychain and proceed with that?
                  2) If so, will users can be able to upgrade the existing app from the appstore?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your answers

> 1) As I don't have backup of certificate and .p12, should I need to raise a request for new certificate from my keychain and proceed with that?

Don't worry, when you like to give new update for your application, create new .p12 file and use it. Certificates are used to basically authenticate your machine with developer account.

> 2) If so, will users can be able to upgrade the existing app from the appstore?

No problem for users, as app store distribution provisioning profile works very different from developer provisioning profile, so no user needs to update.

Just for your info: the signing files for Android are very important, not for iPhone application. For Android, if signing keys are lost, you cannot update apps, whereas for iPhone you can create new certificates and update your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just request a new production certificate from your new machine.
Then use it for your old provisioning profile for the app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes without private key in your keychain, You cant use the existing provision files created with that private key. So you need to create a new Developer/Distribution certificates in developer portal with new Certificates. This will not affect the existing application in appstore.